# animation not being applied in render

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine

I just downloaded a stormtrooper model on blendswap and posed it for a render. Although when I render it, it just renders in the default position. In the viewport it renders with the new pose, although when I fully render it, it goes back to default position.

If you need I can attach screenshots.

Thanks in advance,
Tom.

Comment: could you please share your file? Just the armature, not the character: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Yes, attach screenshots. Don’t crop out the UI. My first guess though is that the Show In Render toggle on the armature modifier is off.

Comment: @TheLabCat Here is a google doc that has the 2 screenshots on: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LZ43ItHHOzbQFQQ77KhVYDQrDehbei0E-BZ7Ndme7AA/edit?usp=sharing (apologies for the long link)

Comment: @Tom_nerd could you attach your blender file?

Comment: @YousufChaudhry here is a link to a google drive which has the file in it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UY9ezwCDSVlrA5G-zKFws2J20JNNW_sf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Tom_nerd There are no keyframes on your rig, it's still...

Comment: @YousufChaudhry Not animating it shouldn’t result in no pose retention at all.

Comment: @Tom_nerd For future reference, edit the question and use the built in image adder, and blend-exchange.com for most files. pasteall.org/blend is an alternative for larger files.

Comment: @TheLabCat Yes, but in case he renders an animation, or skips a frame, it will revert to the original. He probably forgot to keyframe, rendered a short animation or skipped a frame, and no result. He won't get the middle and after animation properties without keyframing. I think you misunderstood me, I said that without the keyframe you won't get the _Animation Data_ for the render.

Comment: @YousufChaudhry But if there are no keyframes at all, it doesn’t have any reason to change. It would stay where it was posed.

Comment: @TheLabCat What you're saying makes sense on my end. But what he did was, I think, was to animate the first frame and then not animate the last frame, or maybe undid or I would guess, deleted the frames. Again, you're right but not a problem since it solved the OP's question,

Comment: @YousufChaudhry I’m concerned about the future. A slight technical misunderstanding like this could lead to massive confusion later on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137121/discussion-between-yousuf-chaudhry-and-thelabcat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your file, there are no animated keyframes appearing. You probably posed it and forgot to keyframe, try posing and keyframing it again and give it a render.